# Linear mixed models and categories

Tags: mixed-model

I have time series data (relative abundance of OTU data from 16S sequencing) from subjects who fall into two categories: acquired illness or no illness. My hypothesis is this: some subjects may have protective, and differentially abundant, microbes that prevent them from acquiring the disease.

I'd like to use all of the time points, with the subject as a random effect (lme4 package in R), but I think this may be a problem. For each subject, they fall solely into the category of either A. acquired disease or B. did not acquire disease. It was my understanding that each random effect had its own distribution of data that a linear model was fitted to, but I don't know what this means if the each distribution only contains data from one of the two categories (+/- disease).

Is it nonsensical to use the linear mixed models in this fashion?